# Android Fragment FragmentStatePagerAdapter change backroundcolor of TextView but only onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

since I am new to the Android genre I hope you might give me a hand here:

The app uses different Fragments which are beeing managed by the a FragmentManager. This class is beeing extended by the FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

If I use this specific Fragment:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by welser on 22.06.2015.
 */
public class RalisierungsFragment extends ListFragment {
    // Store instance variables
    private String title;
    private int page;
    public int value = 111;
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DATUM = "created_at";
    static int [] colors = new int[] {0xF0FFFF, 0xD3D3D3 };
    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    // url to get all products list
    //private static String url_all_products = "http://novaten.cloud.hs-furtwangen.de/phpandroid/get_all_products.php";
    private static String url_all_products = "http://141.28.100.152/phpandroid/get_all_products.php";
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;
    public TextView text;

    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static RalisierungsFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
        RalisierungsFragment rs = new RalisierungsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        rs.setArguments(args);
        return rs;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
        text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); // abgendert
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
         public String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ",value + "");

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATUM);
                        String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_DATUM, date);
                        map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                        map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                        set(products.length());
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_DATUM,TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                            new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.price, R.id.datum, R.id.description});
                            //text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


                            setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });



        }

        public void set(int i){
            value = i;
        }

    }

}
```

The background color should depend on each json String (R.id.name)on the listview. I hope I descriped everything as clear as possible. If there are some further questions please dont hestiate to correct me.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve. Did you want to change the background color of the list view or the background color of each row ?

Comment: The list shows different severities, like the "name" in one row is "critcal" and a other one is "warning". Each time a "critcial" line occurs the word should be emphasized with a different color.. like this one but with different colors [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5am927r8ykbbikc/example_list.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all of you. I decided to simply overwrite the getView() Methode, so I didnt need an extra class.

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    getActivity(), productsList,
                                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_DATUM,TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                                         new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.price, R.id.datum, R.id.description}){


                                @Override
                                public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                                    if ("major".equals(productsList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME))){
                                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                     } else if ("cirtical".equals(productsList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME))){
                                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                     } else if ("warning".equals(productsList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME))) {
                                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                    } else if ("info".equals(productsList.get(position).get(TAG_NAME))) {
                                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    } else {
                                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                    }
                                    return view;
                                }
                            };
                   setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of each line, you will have to use your own adater.

First create xml file with the desired layout for your line. Then create a custom adapter following this skeleton :

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private String[] mStrings;//the array to display
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;

     private YourAdapter(Context context, String[] datas) {
          mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
          mStrings = datas;
    }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
          return mStrings.length();
     }

     @Override
     public long getItemIdAtPosition(int position) {
          return position;
     }

     @Override
     public Object getItemAtPosition(int position) {
          return mStrings[position];
     }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           //the following line is bad in terme of oprimization, you should use a holder, but it is a bit too long to write here, see the link below for example
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row);


           //set the datas and the colors to the row
           TextView textView =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
           textView.setText(mStrings[position]);
           convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.your_color);//you can change the color following the position or the string that you put in
           return convertView;
      }
}
```

Finally in your activity use

```
 YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(this, productList);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For more detailed implementation see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem ist - or at least I am not sure - that the data is beeing loaded dynamically from the web so erverything has to take place in the "RealisierungsFragment" or am I wrong? Using a further adapter wont be the soloution since there are other data also missing which should be shown there...

Comment: The adapter purpose is to dynamiclly build row for you list view with the data you provide to him. So it should be able to work even with no data (in the example above it juste need to have a not null array). So when you fragment become visible and you don't have your data, your adapter will have nothing to display. When you have fetched your data pass them to your adapter (here you will have to add a setter method) and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` and your list view will be updated